# Error creating CSR with config.cnf openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, csr

I am trying to create a CSR using Openssl with predefined configuration. This is for the purpose of government E-Invoice recomendations in Saudi. I have successfully created Public and Private key. But when creating CSR it's showing error as below:

```
Error checking request extension section req_ext
FC620000:error:04000067:object identifier routines:OBJ_txt2obj:unknown object name:crypto\objects\obj_dat.c:438:
FC620000:error:05800077:x509 certificate routines:X509_NAME_ENTRY_create_by_txt:invalid field name:crypto\x509\x509name.c:252:name=registerAddress
FC620000:error:11000095:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:dirname error:crypto\x509\v3_san.c:564:
FC620000:error:11000080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf_int:error in extension:crypto\x509\v3_conf.c:48:section=req_ext, name=subjectAltName, value=dirName:alt_names
```

My config.cnf file data is as below:

```
oid_section = OIDs
[OIDs]
certificateTemplateName = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2

[req]
default_bits = 2048
emailAddress = faheemkurikkal.mp@gmail.common
req_extensions = v3_req
x509_extensions = v3_ca
prompt = no
default_md =sha26
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn


[dn]
C = SA
OU = Ryiad Branch
O = Jarir
CN = 127.0.0.1

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:ZATCA-Code-Signing
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names

[alt_names]
SN=1-AcmeInc|2-EGSUnit|3-123456789
UID=310122393500003
title=1100
registerAddress=MyAddress
businessCategory=Acme Industry
```

I tried all possible settings related to config file. I am new to Openssl and don't have enough knowledge about this.

Comment: This is not programming or development, but you misspelled `oid_section` as `old_section`

Comment: I have updated the question with current error @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Yes `registerAddress` is not among the OIDnames predefined in OpenSSL, so you need to add it the same way you did `certificateTemplateName`. The same is true for `businessCategory` although that wasn't reported because it wasn't reached.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tried removing those entries you noted above and now CSR generation is successful. But I don't know how to define those entries, because I need those entries. Can you guide me on this? I have very basic knowledge on this

Comment: I half take it back; `businessCategory` IS standard (it's X509 15 = 2.5.4.15). `registerAddress` is not, but `registeredAddress` is (X509 26 = 2.5.4.26) -- so that would be quite suitable for use in a certificate, and consistent with most of the other attributes you have; could that be what whoever you are communicating with wants? If so just use those two without defining them.

Comment: But I cannot use that as given above, its showing the error above defined. So how should I use businessCategory and retisteredAddress in config? @dave_thompson_085

Answer (score 0):

I am currently integrating with ZATCA as well. It's a bit late but I faced similar error `Error Loading request extension section req_ext`. I got it solved by putting the line `req_extensions = req_ext` before the line `req_extensions = v3_req`. Consider it as the extension `req_ext` is causing you the error as well.

Edit: Look at my `config.cnf` file. Note that the fields with `__fieldName` are fillable. For example `__emailAddress` shall be replaced with `youremail@domain.com` and so on

```ini
oid_section=OIDS
[ OIDS ]
certificateTemplateName= 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
[req]
default_bits=2048
emailAddress=__emailAddress
req_extensions=v3_req
x509_extensions=v3_Ca
prompt=no
default_md=sha256
req_extensions=req_ext
distinguished_name=dn
[dn]
CN=__commonName
C=__country
OU=__organizationalUnitName
O=__organizationName
[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:PREZATCA-code-Signing
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names
[alt_names]
SN=__serialNumber
UID=__vatNumber
title=__invoiceType
registeredAddress=__registeredAddress
businessCategory=__businessCategory
```

Comment: Can you please share your config data. All CSR generated with my config is not accepting in the compliance API.

Comment: @FaheemMCFC Comment edited, check now

Comment: I tried with your config, but I am getting error in compliance CSID api in sandbox. Error: 'can't parse JSON.  Raw result:
Invalid Request'. Can you help me with this?.

Comment: The 'Can't Parse JSON' Error if I am correct is usually associated with a 400 status code. Usually occurs due to either invalid CSR (missing/ data) or missing headers. I explained the whole process in [This Repo](https://github,com/abrahman-ra/zatca-api-guideline) with sample dummy data [that work] and postman API documentation. Check it out and follow it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem was with the version of openssl I installed. I changed it and now it's working fine..