# Retrieve config data by decoding Certifcate Signing Request (CSR)

Tags: openssl, config, csr

I have CSR with me provided by an authority. I like to generate the config data from that CSR. I already build some `config.cnf` and tried creating the CSR, but when verifying with the authorised platform it's not working. I believe there is some missing values in my `config.cnf`, hence I want to obtain config data from provided CSR. Authorities doesn't provide any config content, hence the problem. How can I obtain full data of `config.cnf` from CSR.

I tried decoding CSR with online decoders, but cannot understand the data properly. I don't have any knowledge on this. This is for Zatca E-Invoice generation which is to be used in Saudi Arabia for business.

The CSR provided by Zatca is below:

> 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

The config data I built is below:

```
oid_section = OIDs
[OIDs]
certificateTemplateName = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2

[req]
default_bits = 2048
emailAddress = faheemkurikkal.mp@gmail.com
req_extensions = v3_req
x509_extensions = v3_ca
prompt = no
default_md =sha26
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn


[dn]
C = SA
OU = TST
O = 3111111111
CN = TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1
DC = extgazt
organizationIdentifier=311190293700003


[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment

[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:ZATCA-Code-Signing
subjectAltName = dirName:alt_names

[alt_names]
SN=1-haya|2-234|3-354
UID=310122393500003
title=1100
registeredAddress=Zatca 3
businessCategory = Food Business3
```

I created CSR with above config.cnf but it's not accepting in Zatca QR verification.   Actually the config data is correct but for E-Invoice QR verification it's not accepting. Only above mentioned CSR is ok.

So I would like to get all data they used in config for creating that CSR.
I have tried everything possible, but because of less knowledge I failed. I have been working on this for one week.

Comment: This is not programming or development, but: **that's not a CSR, it's a cert** and you can display it (locally) with `openssl base64 -d -A <thatbase64 | openssl x509 -inform d -noout -text` but note that a cert contains many fields that _cannot_ be put in a CSR. I don't believe you generated any CSR with the config you show because it contains two errors, the same as in [this similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590061/); after fixing those it creates a CSR containing the extensions from [req_ext] but not those from [v3_req] (if you actually wanted those).

Comment: *You* created a CSR. The CA signed it and produced this *certificate.*

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough knowledge about CSR or cert. The config is provided by Zatca officials and with the same config I successfully generated CSR with openssl. Also with https://certlogik.com/decoder/ I decoded the CSR and it's fine. But I want to get the data of config.cnf used for generating above CSR or Cert @dave_thompson_085

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain more. @user207421

Comment: `openssl req -new -sha256 -key .\PrivateKey.pem -extensions v3_req -config .\config.cnf -out CSR.csr` this is how I created the CSR. @user207421

Comment: @user207421: OP created a CSR which CA rejected; the cert shown is apparently some _other_ party's cert (which the CA _did_ issue -- but not by signing a CSR). Codinoz: you can get the field values in that cert as I showed before, but that doesn't mean the CA will issue a cert with that data to _you_. The CA should issue you a cert only if your request (CSR) accurately describes _your_ identity, not someone else's.